# In xocde 14.3 getting these errors 460 "duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64" in react native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

In react native project while building app from xocode getting these two errors

**460 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64**

**Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

unable to log these. when I click on error nothing happened.

My xcode version is 14.3
and iOS version is 13.4

[image]